# Why does rmarkdow/bookdown make so many passes through the code, executing each chunk at least 5 times?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rendering

I'm rendering a bookdown project to pdf that has many tables, figures, references. When I watch the progress of the build, each R chunk appears to be executed at least 5 times before the pdf file is produced. Some of the R chunks call sqlserver databases that execute slowly, pushing the rendering time into the 5 minute territory for a 190 page document. I'm looking for general advice on how to avoid executing each chunk so many times to speed up the process.

Comment: I never observed this behaviour. In my experience, R Markdown adds minimal overhead compared to running just an R script. How do you figure that chunks are run multiple times?

Comment: I'm watch the build window and see the chunk commands go by and every time it hits the database calls there's the 5-10 second delay in processing commands. Simple chunks go by quickly. The issue is that the chunks are executed multiple times (up to 5 times)

Comment: Are you sure? You can name the chunks with `{r chunk1}` to make sure you don't see different chunks being executed. As I said, I've never experienced anything like this and I've bee using R Markdown for years...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I've named nearly all the chunks for cross reference purposes in the text. Everything about each pass is identical, including the percentages of chunks processed, the same pauses at slowly executing chunks, warning messages, etc. All repeated 4-5 times. Compiling the book now takes 7 minutes (even to generate error messages.) I'm starting to have other problems with compiling the book as well so maybe this issue is a red herring. I can't find documentation that explains how it's 'supposed' to work. My past experience mirrors yours.